# 2 function in onPressed

Tags: flutter, dart

I am very new to Flutter and I want to put 2 function on onPressed button.

I try this

```
ElevatedButton(
     onPressed: () {isConnected ? () =>_sendMessage('1') : null; checkBiometric();},
     child: Text('ON'),
),
```

but only the `checkBiometric` is working.

Edit: `checkBiometric` must be satisfied first before `isConnected ? () =>_sendMessage('1') : null` to execute.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `await` to complete the first one.
Do it like this,

```dart
ElevatedButton(
     onPressed: () async {
     await checkBiometric();
     if(isConnected) _sendMessage('1');     
   },
```

Doing `isConnected ? () =>_sendMessage('1')` creates another nested anonymous function.

More about [Asynchronous programming](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await).

Comment: I want `checkBiometric` to be satisfied first before `isConnected ? () =>_sendMessage('1') : null` to execute.

Comment: is `checkBiometric` future method?

Comment: `void checkBiometric() async { ...` the code is long, cant comment it

Comment: Convert it to `Future<void> checkBiometric() `

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting it like this-

```
ElevatedButton(
     onPressed: () { 
     checkBiometric();
     if (isConnected){
      _sendMessage("1");
      }
     
      }
     child: Text('ON'),
),
```

Comment: I want `checkBiometric` to be satisfied first before `isConnected ? () =>_sendMessage('1') : null` to execute.

Comment: Them simply call it before the if statement. I have updated my answer.